# Put CheckBox and Label on the Same Line MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, alignment

I've searched the forums and have tried many options but I still can't get this to work.
As stated I'm trying to get my Label and Checkbox on the same line.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="editor">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gen_Print_Due_Before_Run)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Gen_Print_Due_Before_Run)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gen_Print_Due_Before_Run)
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
}
.col {
    float: left;
    width: 50%
}

.editor label {
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: right;
}
.editor input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 80px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like Paulie_D said, float the check box. Either that or use display:inline;
make sure to use clear:both; under the html to ensure they don't float over the top of any other elements.

Answer (score 1):

working solution for me is:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
       <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox"> LabelTextHere
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer that solved this for me at [ASP.NET MVC: Align checkbox and label on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55915175/asp-net-mvc-align-checkbox-and-label-on-same-line)

This is the css:

```
.editor .control-label {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}

.editor input[type="checkbox"] {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
}

.editor:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working solution for me is

```
<label class="control-label" for="">@Html.CheckBox("IsAllow_MobileNotification",false) 
Allow Mobile Notifications.</label>
```

Got from link https://forums.asp.net/t/1978747.aspx?Render+Label+beside+Checkbox+in+MVC+4+View